# Cells are birthed and killed in the same generation of Conway's Game of Life

Tags: java, arrays, conways-game-of-life

With some help, I've created a temporary 2D array called nextStep to handle the new cells that come to life in the colony of cells-but for some reason my code is still birthing and killing cells in the same generation, rather than applying the necessary changes in the next generation. Any help would be very appreciated.

```
public void updateColony() {
nextStep = new int[colony.length][colony[0].length];
for (int i = 0; i < colony.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < colony[i].length; j++) {
        evolution(i, j, colony);
    }
}
colony = nextStep;
}
public void setCellAlive (int row, int col){
if (row <= numberRows){
          nextStep [row][col] = 1;
    }else{
    System.out.println ("Index out of range.");
    }
}
public void setCellDead (int row, int col){
    if (row <= numberRows){
        nextStep [row][col]=0;

    }else{
         System.out.println ("Index out of range.");
    }
}
private void evolution(int i, int j, int [][] colony) {
    int left = 0, right = 0, up = 0, down = 0;
    int UpperLeft = 0, UpperRight = 0, LowerLeft = 0, LowerRight = 0;

    if (j < colony.length - 1) {
        right = colony[i][j + 1];
        if(i>0)
            UpperRight = colony[i - 1][j + 1];
        if (i < colony.length - 1)
            LowerRight = colony[i + 1][j + 1];
    }

    if (j > 0) {
        left = colony[i][j - 1];
        if (i > 0)
            UpperLeft = colony[i - 1][j - 1];
        if (i< colony.length-1)
            LowerLeft = colony[i + 1][j - 1];
    }

    if (i > 0)
        up = colony[i - 1][j];
    if (i < colony.length - 1)
        down = colony[i + 1][j];

    int sum = left + right + up + down + UpperLeft + UpperRight
            + LowerLeft
            + LowerRight;

    if (colony[i][j] == 1) {
        if (sum < 2)
            setCellDead (i,j);
        if (sum > 3)
            setCellDead(i,j);
    }

    else {
        if (sum == 3)
            setCellAlive (i,j);
    }

}
```

Comment: When you initialize an int array, all the values are default set to 0. The only place I see you set a cell being alive is if the sum is equal to 3. At the moment, Sums 1, 2, 4 through 8 are all dead. Is this intended?

Comment: I have another method where I set certain cells alive (1), and then apply the evolution method to evolve them.

Comment: Comment out setCellDead method calls. If the same thing happens, you're not setting cell life properly. If things are fixed, then you are calling setCellDead too often. If there's a completely different unexpected outcome, you have a logic error.

Comment: @Compass Once I removed all of the method calls, it started evolving the cells more correctly than it did before, but now I am unsure of where I would utilize setCellDead since the program functions more correctly without it.

Comment: Typically, you'd only use a setCellDead implementation if you were to clone the entire array from the previous generation (i.e. some values are already 1.) In your case, you started off with a completely zeroed new generation array. setCellDead on an already dead cell doesn't change its state, so the only place you'd be affecting your code negatively is if you are setting a previously living cell to death or vice versa. Assume everything is dead unless it passes the criteria of being alive.

Comment: @Compass I have an if check in the attached code to determine whether or not the cell is alive before setting it dead, perhaps it is not functioning as it should?

Comment: Potentially. You've narrowed it down to a logic pattern that doesn't make sense and you just need to figure out where it is. You might have to just step through using a debugger, and see where the methods break.